# Recursive function inequality

Tags: inequality, recursion

Let $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\tfrac{1}{1+x_n}$.
I want to proof that for every $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ with $m\leq n$, the inequality $|x_{n}-x_{m}|\leq 2^{-m}$ is true.

This can be done by induction over $m$.
Two facts I found out are

1. $\tfrac{1}{2} \leq x_n \leq 1$
2. For every $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality $|x_{n+1}-x_{m+1}|\leq \tfrac{1}{2}|x_n-x_m|$ is true.

Now the induction:
Begin: or $m=1$ we can see with 1. that it is true.
The Hypothesis is
$|x_{n}-x_{m+1}|\leq 2^{-(m+1)}$

With 2. we can see that
$ |x_{n+1}-x_{m+1}| \leq \tfrac{1}{2}|x_n-x_m| \leq \tfrac{1}{2} 2^{-m} = 2^{-(m+1)}$

But how to get from
$|x_{n}-x_{m+1}|$ to $|x_{n+1}-x_{m+1}|$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I solved it by myself.

$|x_{n}-x_{m+1}| \leq |x_{n+1}-x_{m+1}|$ because $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$ for every $x_n \in (-1, \tfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$ and as $\lim(x_n)=\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for $n \rightarrow ∞$ the statement is true.

Comment: @CalvinLin But $x_n=0.7$ is not in $(-1, \tfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$

Comment: Ah, ic. You might want to state that first (I was just operating with part 1).